# ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 87, character 6

Tags: android, ios, flutter, runtime

I'm facing an error with Android Studio after app running on Android device in flutter.

Error is here :

> "ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 87,
> character 6".

I didn't find any solution about it and don't know how to fix it. please help me . thank you.
[here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7dfr.png)

I didn't understand it and how will it fix?

Comment: Hey, please share more detail about the code that you've problem with.

Comment: Judging by the red dot in the Dart Analysis tab, I assume you have a syntax error somewhere. Just open the tab and read what the Dart Analysis server tells you.

Comment: how to open tab? and how the find file which has error?

Comment: i really don't get any red dot error in the Dart Analysis tab.